# Navbar not centering correctly, slightly more white space to the left of it

Tags: html, css, navbar, centering, navigationbar

My navbar is not centering properly and it's driving me nuts - there's slightly more white space on the left side of it.  Thank you so much in advance.  Here is the code

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul class="navitems">
        <li>
            <a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="podcasts.html">Podcasts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="articles.html">Articles</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="merch.html">Merch</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0
}

.navbar {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.navitems ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.navitems li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
    padding-bottom: 1.5%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 12%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.navitems a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: georgia;
}
.navitems li:hover a{
    transition: all ease-in-out .5s;
    color: #f88122;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `<ul>` tag has got default `padding-inline-start` style so it is needed to reset that value.
2. To align items in the middle, it is needed to set `vertical-align: middle` on `<li>` items.
3. `.navitems ul` indicates the `<ul>` selector inside `.navitems` selector. And from your html code, you should change it to `ul.navitems`.

Below is the working snippet.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.navbar {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

ul.navitems {
  list-style: none;
  
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.navitems li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
  padding-bottom: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 12%;
  font-size: 20px;
  
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navitems a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: georgia;
}

.navitems li:hover a {
  transition: all ease-in-out .5s;
  color: #f88122;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="navitems">
    <li><a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="podcasts.html">Podcasts</a></li>
    <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="merch.html">Merch</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Kyle don't forget that you can mark a question as 'accepted' and/or upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you check your code, you will find that your selector is wrong in the `.navitems` you don't need to add **ul** and there is **padding-left** for **ul**, so the padding should be zero.
Good luck

```css
body {
    margin:0
    }

    .navbar {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
    .navitems { /* Change the css selector */
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0 !important; /* Add this line */
    }
    .navitems li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
    padding-bottom: 1.5%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 12%;
    font-size: 20px;
    }
    .navitems a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: georgia;
    }
    .navitems li:hover a{
    transition: all ease-in-out .5s;
    color: #f88122;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

```html
<div class="navbar">

    <ul class="navitems p-0">
    <li><a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a></li><li><a href="podcasts.html">Podcasts</a></li><li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li><li><a href="merch.html">Merch</a></li><li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>   
    </div>
```